# Min-Max Checkbox Selection in Form [Code Modification Help]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This code successfully greys out all other checkboxes with the same class name when 3 are selected but does not require the user to select at least 1.

How can I modify it to do that?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var $checkboxWrapper = $('div.checkboxmetiers');

    $checkboxWrapper.find('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
        if( $checkboxWrapper.find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
             $(this).prop('checked', false).change();
        }

        if( $checkboxWrapper.find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length === 3) {
            $checkboxWrapper.find('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').closest('label').css({'opacity': '0.5', 'pointer-events' : 'none'})
        } else {
            $checkboxWrapper.find('label').css({'opacity': '', 'pointer-events' : ''})
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Please try things for yourself before asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for but it can give you an idea.

Add that in your `.on('change')`

```
  if( $checkboxWrapper.find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length < 1) {
    console.log("select at least 1.")
    $checkboxWrapper.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('required',true);
  }else if( $checkboxWrapper.find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0 ){
    $checkboxWrapper.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('required',false); 
  }
```